# Do horns affect AI?

Tags: american-truck-simulator

I like overtaking AI slowpokes that hamper the overtaking lane. I read [this Steam Community post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/270880/discussions/0/135508833654043623/), but there's no consensus.

1. Will honking goad them to turn to the right-hand traveling lane?
2. If not, how can I goad them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL; DR: No they don't. I'll quote answers from https://redd.it/bpv86n.

> What I've noticed is being significantly faster works most of the time. As long as there is space the AI car will merge to the right and let you pass if you're approaching from behind on a collision course.
>
> Speed works best, as long as the AI sees that it has space, it will go there. Horns just make you feel better :)
>
> [With certain AI mods it becomes consistent, the AI either speed up or merge the moment you horn, the mod that I have even makes the AI back up if they have space to let me pass through](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1127826231).

Answer (score 2):

Horns don't affect them. Though if you travel in the left lane at high speed (you really shouldn't with a truck!) and the vehicle before you has a chance to move to the right lane, they usually do so by themselves, especially slow ones like other trucks or buses. They will never do this if the right lane is occupied.

This only applies when driving in the left lane(s), never when driving in the right-most one.